# facing issue while restrict number and special characters in angularjs

Tags: javascript, angularjs, html

I want to restrict the special characters and space in the input text field. I used the

`ng-pattern="/^(?=.*[0-9])(?=.*[a-zA-Z])([a-zA-Z0-9]+)$/"`

to restrict the special characters. but its not working. How can i achieve that?

here is my html code:

```
<form name="JobDescriptionForm" id="JobDescriptionForm" class="form-horizontal" role="form" novalidate>
    <div class="col-md-12 col-sm-12 col-lg-12 nopadding select-job">
        <label for="createJob" class="col-md-12 col-sm-12 col-lg-12 nopadding"> Create Job </label>
        <input type="text" ng-model="price" name="price_field" ng-pattern="/^(?=.*[0-9])(?=.*[a-zA-Z])([a-zA-Z0-9]+)$/" required>
        <span ng-show="JobDescriptionForm.price_field.$error.pattern">Not a valid number!</span>
    </div>
</form>
```

I' m referring this code because I'm little confused for is there any need to write something in Controller? What to do in this case?

Comment: What exactly is not working? What do you expect as a valid input and what do you expect to be invalid. Give some examples.

Comment: actually I want to restrict the special characters and space in the input text field.

Comment: i found many example on staskoverflow but they used ng-pattern-restrict but didnt work for me

Comment: `type="number"` is also not working?

Comment: You are aware that your regular expression requires the input to have both a digit and a letter? Works quite well with a simpler regex here: https://jsfiddle.net/jacquesc/L33fshps/

Comment: @jcaron Thank you its working.

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you use ng-pattern="/^[a-zA-Z0-9]+$/" if all that you want is to restrict special characters and space?

And check your code as well, your end tag for "form" has a typo, you wrote "